# How does this partitioning problem map to studied problems?

Tags: algorithms, partitions

I have a real-world (see background below) problem wherein a set $S = \{A,B,C,D...\}$ needs to be partitioned into set $P = \{ \{A,B\},\{D\},\{E,F\},\{C,G,H\},...\}$ where $P$ is required to have the fewest possible elements. There are restrictions on which elements of $S$ can be partitioned together; at any time I can evaluate a function $f(A,B)$ which tells me if partition $A=\{X,Y,Z...\}$ can be merged with partition $B =\{W,U,V,...\}$.

**Does this problem map onto any studied partitioning problems?** For example, a google search turned up the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), but there are some distinct differences that I wouldn't know how to reconcile.

#### Background

My motivation centers around the following problem. Consider a series of overlapping circles in a 2D space:
[image: circles]

My goal is to group these circles based on if they have mutual overlap, and find the fewest such groups. For example, circles ABC could be grouped together because they have a non-empty region of overlap, but ABCD cannot. There also may be multiple ways to achieve the fewest number of groups. For example:

1. A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
2. AB, CD, EF, G, H
3. ABC, DE, FG, H
4. ABC, DEF, G, H
5. AB, CD, EFG, H
6. etc...

are all partitions of the set of circles, but 3, 4, and 5 represent the partitioning with the fewest groups.

Comment: Do you want to ask about the general problem at the top or the specific problem at the bottom?  It is an instance of set cover.

Comment: @D.W. My focus is indeed on the specific problem. But I wrote the question under the assumption there is no difference between the two. If there is, I would love to know what it is. 
I will google set covering. Thanks.

Comment: The more general problem might be harder and doesn't seem well-specified, because it does not provide any way to tell whether a proposed solution is valid.  In the general problem you assume that the only way to find a solution is to start by merging smaller partitions; and whether the final solution is valid might depend on the way in which you got to it (the order in which you merged smaller groups).  The specific problem does not have that problem; given a proposed partition, we can tell whether it is valid.